# pyspark self class variable using to read csv file for dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have to call csv file to read data frame as below format, i can read normal file read but using self variable , i am not aware of it. kindly help us.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
class ChargePointsETLJob:
    input_path = 'data/input/electric-chargepoints-2017.csv'
    output_path = 'data/output/chargepoints-2017-analysis'

    def __init__(self):
        self.spark_session = (SparkSession.builder
                                          .master("local[*]")
                                          .appName("ElectricChargePointsETLJob")
                                          .getOrCreate())
    def extract(self):
        pass

    def transform(self, df):
        pass

    def load(self, df):
        pass

    def run(self):
        self.load(self.transform(self.extract()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

class ChargePointsETLJob:
    input_path = 'data/input/electric-chargepoints-2017.csv'
    output_path = 'data/output/chargepoints-2017-analysis'

    def __init__(self):
        self.spark_session = (SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")
        .appName("ElectricChargePointsETLJob")
        .getOrCreate())

    def extract(self):
        df = self.spark_session.read.format("csv").\
             option("header", "true").load(self.input_path)
        return df

    def transform(self, df):

        df = df.groupby('CPID').agg(max('PluginDuration').alias('max_duration'),\
             avg('PluginDuration').alias('avg_duration'))\
             .withColumnRenamed("CPID","chargepoint_id")\
            .select('chargepoint_id',round('max_duration',2)\
            .alias('max_duration'),round('avg_duration',2)\
            .alias('avg_duration')).drop_duplicates()
        return df

    def load(self, df):
        df.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet")\
        .mode("overwrite").save(self.output_path)

    def run(self):
        self.load(self.transform(self.extract()))`
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.